# How to copy specific values in one pandas data frame into another?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe with one column and with header `DD` as given below.

[image]

I want to create a new data-frame out of `df` as follows.

```
Name  >             <NR-AR>  > <NR-AR-LBD>  > <NR-AhR> > <NR-ER>  > <NR-ER-LBD>  > <NR-PPAR-gamma>  > <SR-ARE>
NCGC00261443-01      0             0            0          0          0             0             0
```

So the pattern should be like above.

Comment: No images, only text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
L = ['NAME','NCGC00261443-01','> <NR-AR>','0','> <NR-AR-LBD>','0',' > <NR-AhR>','0']
df = pd.DataFrame({'DD': L + L[:4]})
df.loc[9] = 'NCGC00261600-01'
print (df)
                 DD
0              NAME
1   NCGC00261443-01
2         > <NR-AR>
3                 0
4     > <NR-AR-LBD>
5                 0
6        > <NR-AhR>
7                 0
8              NAME
9   NCGC00261600-01
10        > <NR-AR>
11                0
```

---

```
#reshape to 2 column df
df = pd.DataFrame(df['DD'].values.reshape(-1, 2), columns=['a','b'])
print (df)
               a                b
0           NAME  NCGC00261443-01
1      > <NR-AR>                0
2  > <NR-AR-LBD>                0
3     > <NR-AhR>                0
4           NAME  NCGC00261600-01
5      > <NR-AR>                0

#value NAME distinguish first value of new row
#reshape and change ordering of columns by reindex
#last set default index values (0,1,2...)
df1 = (df.set_index([df['a'].eq('NAME').cumsum(), 'a'])['b']
        .unstack()
        .reindex(columns=pd.unique(df['a']))
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
a             NAME > <NR-AR> > <NR-AR-LBD>  > <NR-AhR>
0  NCGC00261443-01         0             0           0
1  NCGC00261600-01         0          None        None
```

Detail:

```
print (df['a'].eq('NAME').cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you out

```
import pandas as pd

df=df.dropna()  
col_name=[]
data=[]
for idx, val in enumerate(df['DD']):
    if idx %2 ==0:
        col_name.append(val)
    else:
        data.append(val)

df1=pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=col_name)
```

Comment: shape of my dataframe is `(1, 3574)`, so I am getting an error which says `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 3574), indices imply (3574, 3574)`